# "IF" condition to compare two arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, object, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have two array

```php
$array1 = array(25) {
  ["ID"]=>
  int(508)
  ["label"]=>
  string(8) "Document"
  ["value"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    object(WP_Term)#11926 (10) {
      ["term_id"]=>
      int(25)
      ["name"]=>
      string(6) "note 1"
      ["slug"]=>
      string(6) "note-1"
             }
           }
  ["menu_order"]=>
  int(0)
...
}

$array2 = array(25) {
  ["ID"]=>
  int(526)
  ["label"]=>
  string(10) "Document 2"
  ["value"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["value"]=>
      string(5) "#link"
      ["label"]=>
      string(4) "link"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
      ["value"]=>
      string(5) "#link"
      ["label"]=>
      string(4) "link"
    }
  }
...
}
```

I would like to create an IF condition - if the array contains "object (WP_Term)" then print "correct".

I am trying to use in_array() function but am not getting result instead of having existence. in_array() function worked for object array  ? :

```
if(in_array('object', $array1)) {
print 'correct';}
```

If not then what is alternative to check if array is inclusion of object array or not. 
Unfortunately it does not work. Please help me create the condition. thx

Comment: Please add more details than "does not work": is it always "correct"? Never? Is there an error (if there is, add it to the question)? Also it's important to note that your "object (WP_Term)" is not in your Array, it is in an Array inside your Array. This is important, your approach must be more subtle, and we might need more details: will it always be the case? can it be nested more levels deep?

Comment: if possible post your full check to help you better!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the instance of the class 'WP_Term' is not in a certain level, the array must be searched recursively. This can be done with [array_walk_recursive](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php). I created this function:

```
//return true if arr contains an object with className
function arrayContainObject(array $arr, $className){
  $contain = false;
  array_walk_recursive($arr,function($val,$key) use($className, &$contain){
    if($val instanceOf $className) $contain = true;
  });
  return $contain;
}
```

Example of using the function:

```
//Test Data
class WPterm{}

$arr = [1,2,3,
  [4,5, (new WPTerm)]
];

//check
if( arrayContainObject($arr, 'WPTerm')){
  echo "Array contain object WPterm";
}
```